# How to make peer connection between two AWS VPC's which has same CIDR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cidr, vpc

I have tried to make peer connection between Two aws VPC's which has same CIDR. While I'm creating a peer connection it says it cannot create peer connection between two VPC's because of same CIDR.

Comment: you cannot do it directly. if rebuilding one of the VPCs is an option, rebuild and give it a different CIDR. If rebuilding is not an option, setup a VPN tunnel between then with something like OpenVPN

Comment: At the moment i can't rebuild it. therefore i  also think best option is to tunneling two VPC's with VPN. Thanks

Comment: yep. this sort of sucks, but moving forward you can ensure your VPC don't have overlapping CIDRs to ensure you can peer them if needed

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The precondition is that the VPCs do not have overlapping cidr block.

Please refer to below amazon documentation for the same.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/vpc-peering-overview.html